# I am looking for a C++ library which processes debug symbols out of a .PDB document

Tags: c++, debugging, symbols, dbghelp, dia-sdk

Creating a module that will decode structures defined in a PDB document; can anyone provide me with a module that would extract the required debugging symbols from the PDB document? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Debug Interface Access (DIA) SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx).  It's COM-based, but it's the most powerful and flexible way to deal with PDBs, and it abstracts away all of the version-to-version PDB format changes.  It ships with Visual Studio, and the headers and libraries can be found under your VS installation directory.

MSDN also has a fairly complete example of [dumping a PDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd8h6f46.aspx) that includes dumping out type information.

The alternative to DIA is the [Debug Help (DbgHelp) library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  It has a simpler interface, but it exposes less functionality than DIA.  For what you want, I imagine you'd use the [`SymGetTypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681349%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.